# EXC BAD ACCESS in main

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a pernicious `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` bug.  I have enabled zombie tracking, but instead of producing a specific stack trace, the program always stops in main at
`return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));`

Does anyone know why I don't have a meaningful stack trace?  The app uses core data and much of the core data activity is wrappedup in `performBlockAndWait` methods - could that have something to do with it?

I also have a log message from NSZombieEnabled that says `*** -[_PFArray release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x395d0fe0`.  Is there any way of finding out what was originally allocated at  the address in the log message?

Thanks

Comment: Whenever you reference a deallocated object this happens. Because of the way Objective-C works, you the debugger doesn't stop at the location of the violation. You must enable Zombies and setup a breakpoint in Objective-C exceptions to get more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is. Run your app with he instruments ON THE SIMULATOR. Select the Zombies instrument and perform the exact steps that make your app crash. The Zombies instrument is available only on the Simulator since you have more RAM on the Mac than on an iOS device.

Comment: George - thanks for that tip - it worked perfectly and at least now I know that the error is occurring deep inside core data.  The object in question gets malloc'ed in `newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT` and then autoreleased twice by `[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest]` and `[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error]`.  Time for me to go digging further - thanks again

Comment: Glad to help out. It might also help to encapsulate the crashing code in a try-catch block and print out the exception. It also prevents it from crashing which is always a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) tutorial about crashes and figuring out what to do. Pay close attention to this part:

> An exception happens when the program is caught doing something it
>   shouldn’t have done. What you’re looking at now is the aftermath of
>   this exception: the app did something wrong, the exception has been
>   thrown, and Xcode shows you the results. Ideally, you’d want to see
>   exactly where that exception gets thrown. Fortunately, you can tell
>   Xcode to pause the program at just that moment, using an Exception
>   Breakpoint. A breakpoint is a debugging tool that pauses your program
>   at a specific moment.